# After reversing list elements are changing?

Tags: python

after I reverse my list list elements are changing not reversing properly
here is my first code

```
def reverse_fib_series(num):
    x = []
    for i in range(num):
        if i == 0:
            x.append(0)
        elif i == 1:
            x.append(1)
        else:
            x.append(sum(reverse_fib_series(i)[-2:]))
    return x

print(reverse_fib_series(11))
```

it returns `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]`

if I want to reverse it

```
def reverse_fib_series(num):
    x = []
    for i in range(num):
        if i == 0:
            x.append(0)
        elif i == 1:
            x.append(1)
        else:
            x.append(sum(reverse_fib_series(i)[-2:]))
    return x[::-1]

print(reverse_fib_series(11))
```

it returns `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]`. I do not know why?

i am trying to solve the following exercise:
"In Fibonacci Numbers, each number progresses as the sum of the two preceding numbers, such as `0,1,1,2,3,5,8,` ... In this question you are given a number `(0 <N <20)`. Accordingly, write the program that prints all Fibonacci numbers backwards from the Nth Fibonacci number."

Comment: You should either use recursion or a loop. Doing both the way that you are makes little sense.

Comment: why cant you just find the series and reverse it?

Comment: You can just return `a[::-1]`...

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you reverse the list in each recursive call, rather than only reversing it once at the end -- so instead of summing the last two elements of the series to get the next element, you're summing the *first* two elements, which are always 0 and 1.  That's why every element of the series after the first two becomes 1.  (The list isn't changing when you reverse it at the end, the computation of the series is broken because you're reversing it each time.)

You could write the function so that it builds the series in-place from back to front, or you could fix this by simplifying the loop body to eliminate the unnecessary recursion, but this is a good opportunity to learn the concept of composing two simple things to produce one more complicated thing.  :)  Rather than trying to do it all at once, take the working (if sub-optimal) function you already have to produce the Fibonacci series, and then reverse it afterwards:

```
def fib_series(num):
    x = []
    for i in range(num):
        if i == 0:
            x.append(0)
        elif i == 1:
            x.append(1)
        else:
            x.append(sum(fib_series(i)[-2:]))
    return x

def reverse_fib_series(num):
    return fib_series(num)[::-1]
```

Note that your `fib_series` function can be a little simpler than what you wrote; you don't need to recursively call `fib_series` to get the last two numbers, because you already have them stored in `x`:

```
def fib_series(num):
    x = []
    for i in range(num):
        if i == 0:
            x.append(0)
        elif i == 1:
            x.append(1)
        else:
            x.append(sum(x[-2:]))
    return x
```

or you could make it a little shorter by writing it as a generator:

```
def fib_series(num):
    x = [0, 1]
    x.extend(sum(x[-2::]) for _ in range(num - 2))
    return x[:num]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
def reverse_fib_series(num):
    x = []
    for i in range(num):
        if i == 0:
            x.append(0)
        elif i == 1:
            x.append(1)
        else:
            x.append(sum(reverse_fib_series(i)[-2:]))
    return x

print(reverse_fib_series(11)[::-1])
```

reverse the return value because you use recursion in the function

Answer (score 0):

Because you are reversing array inside of a recursive function. It adds one number and reverse. And it keeps repeating the process.

This code will hel

```
def reverse_fib_series(num):
    x = []
    for i in range(num):
       if i == 0:
           x.append(0)
       elif i == 1:
           x.append(1)
       else:
           x.append(sum(reverse_fib_series(i)[-2:]))
   return x

reversed = reverse_fib_series(11)[::-1]
print(reversed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another ways, using `[].insert(0, sum())`

```
def reverse_fib_loop(n: int):
    lx = []
    for i in range(n):
        if i > 1:
            lx.insert(0, sum(lx[:2]))
        else:
            lx.insert(0, i)
    return lx

def reverse_fib_recursion(size: int):
    def wrapped(lx: list, sn: int, n: int):
        if n > 0:
            lx.insert(0, sn)
            sn = sum(lx[:2]) if len(lx) >= 2 else 1
            return wrapped(lx, sn, n-1)
        return lx
    return wrapped([], 0, size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input('N='))
    print(reverse_fib_loop(N))
    print(reverse_fib_recursion(N))
```